# How to configure Windows Server for "Enhanced RDP Security"

Tags: security, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016, rdp

According to Microsoft's Open Specification, there are two "flavours" of [RDP security](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-rdpbcgr/65b65e36-b87a-4f2e-ab49-492d33f21c8f): a "Standard" and "[Enhanced RDP Security](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-rdpbcgr/592a0337-dc91-4de3-a901-e1829665291d)". How can I configure Windows Server to use "Enhanced RPD Security", please? How can I determine and configure which "External Security Protocol" is used, please?

I've spent several hours in the system settings and Registry Editor, and I could not find any configuration items which might allow me to configure these RDP host settings, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure enhanced RDP security Option through GPO. It is important to understand, that 'enhanced' is neither a function level nor an option; its a concept, achived by using the correct setting.

The Items you are searchivn for are stored in

```
Computer Policy > Administrative Templates > Windows Components
  > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Security
```

- Client connection encryption level: Set this to 'High' level, so your Remote Desktop sessions are secured with 128-bit encryption
- Require user authentication for remote connections by using Network Level Authentication – Set this to Enabled

Additionally, you will have to use certificate authentication and (this is important) use the RDS Gateway role to encrypt the RDP traffic. TLS encapsulation (like HTTPS/TLS) is a feature of RDS Gateway, not plain session hosts.

To further improve RDP security, Windows does offer the option to lockout RDP login for a certain period of time, after a certain number of incorrect guesses. I would strongly recommend to use that for the collection you'd like to secure.

Comment: Thank you for a prompt response, @bjoster! However, [in this documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-rdpbcgr/6e547618-4755-41cb-9b3b-c9075565b80d) in the last paragraph it says that _"When a client connects to a server configured for Enhanced RDP Security, the selected encryption level returned to the client is ENCRYPTION_LEVEL_NONE (0)."_ So, to my understanding, the Encryption Level is irrelevant when "External Security Protocol" is used. But I cannot figure out how to configure RDP to use one of the "External Security Protocols". Would you please know?